# Storing data locally in browser and sending to server

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, html5-filesystem

I have read about HTML Filesystem and LocalStorage but I'm not sure what is the best way to implement what I need, if it is all possible.

Basically what I need is for the browser to store some data, preferably XML format, and then send this to server. My ideal implementation is writing to a text file and then uploading this file to the server. But I understand this is not possible to do locally in browsers.

Also I read that Filesystem is not being supported anymore. So is Localstorage the only option to store information in client side?

The biggest problem I would have with Localstorage is that I might have multiple pages, but I need all of them to write to one place.

For example let say I have a web app and the user starts with page A, then navigates to page B and then page C and so on. I need to store some information on each page, and then finally, say page D, I want to send all the previously stored data to the server.

So firstly, am I trying to do something impossible?
If not, what is the best way to go about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply answer your question, yes, you can achieve that. You can store anything in key value pairs in the local storage from different pages and you can send it to the server whenever ready. You can also look at session based storage if you want it to be saved only for a session.

Comment: Thank you for session based storage. That could be the way to go as I need all information in one session in one place.